# Write to a file steam without a file existing on the hard drive in C

Tags: c++, c, input

Is this possible in the C language? Or even C++? I prefer to know for C.

For example, say I had a function that reads a text file and does something with it. If the user did not specify an input text file and I wanted to use that function for stdin; **Is it possible to write stdin to a file stream** as if it were coming from a file read so it can be used in the same method that normally just takes input files?

A way around this of course is that I could take stdin, write it to a temp file, then pass the temp file to the function that normally would take an input file. I've searched online and asked tutors at university but am not getting any solutions. Has anyone ever accomplished this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your function has a prototype say

```
void add(FILE *fp,<rest of the argument>)
{
}
```

The you can directly pass

```
add(stdin,<rest of the arguments>);
```

Because stdin is of type `FILE *`

```
FILE *stdin;
```

No need to read from stdin and store it in some file and and later send that file pointer to your API.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Is there a way to get this to work after prompting the user for input? Currently I am using fgets after a print statement. @Gopi

Answer (score 1):

`STDIN` is open for you automatically, so just read from STDIN. There are several ways of doing it, but basically STDIN is file descriptor 0.

```
int filedes = 0;
if(/* argv[1] is a file name */)
    filedes = open(argv[1], flags);

read(filedes, bufr, size);
```